# keep references to window.open windows after parent refresh

Tags: javascript, jquery

I open some windows using window.open() so I can communicate between parents/ children using JavaScript.

I have this scenario:

Open a window using window.open(), and push it to an array (can have multiple children windows)
Reload/ refresh the parent window.
The parent window has lost its connection to the child windows, previously stored in an array.
The child windows can still call window.opener, though...

I need a way for the parent window to recognise its children again after reload, so it can pass variables/ call functions etc.

how can I do this?

current code looks like:

```
var opened_windows = new Array;

$(document).ready(function(){
    $('a[data-open-js]').click(function(){
        var link = $(this).attr('href');
        opened_windows.push(window.open(link));
        return false;
    });
});


// call functions from the opened windows when something happens in the parent
function update_all_children(jobref, new_num_saved_jobs){
    for(var i = 0; i < opened_windows.length; i++){
        opened_windows[i].update_saved_btns(jobref, new_num_saved_jobs);
    }
}
```

Comment: You could have the parent trigger a delayed callback in the child windows that will use their window.opener reference to insert the child window reference back into the opened_windows array.

Comment: @Shilly the thing is, the parent cant trigger anything in the child windows, as it has no reference to them on reload

Comment: Send the trigger to the child window before the refresh/reload and delay it with a timeout or a callback so it will trigger after the parent has reloaded.